# Bigquery library for Python error: Unexpected end of stream: RLE Decoding retrieved less values: 0 then num values: 113

Tags: google-bigquery, pybigquery

Im having a big time trying to solve this exception on Bigquery library for Python, using the method "**load_table_from_dataframe**":

```py
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: Failed to import values for column 'status': Unexpected end of stream: RLE Decoding retrieved less values: 0 then num values: 113
```

I have tried to parse None to empty strings, to NA, etc. But still have the same issue. It appears to only happen with strings columns. Any help with this?

EDIT: Has happened also with other string columns. Not just this one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the table schema itself. The string column must have "mode":"NULLABLE" instead of "mode":"REQUIRED" because otherwise Bigquery expect the column to not be null.